# Is it possible to apply `smerge-keep-mine` for all the conflicts by using a single keybinding?

Tags: smerge

I am using `smerge` to resolve conflicts in order to apply merge. I am applying one by one for `smerge-keep-mine` to all conflicts, which I belive equivalent for `git merge --strategy-option ours`

`[Q]` Is it possible to apply `smerge-keep-mine` for all the conflicts by using a single keybinding?

config:

```
(defun smerge-try-smerge ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "^<<<<<<< " nil t)
      (require 'smerge-mode)
      (smerge-mode 1))))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'smerge-try-smerge t)
(add-hook 'after-revert-hook 'smerge-try-smerge t)

(defun smerge-next-safe ()
    "returns t on success, nil otherwise"
  (condition-case err
      (not (smerge-next))
    ('error
     nil)))

(require 'vc)
(defun next-conflict ()  ;; key-binding
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer (current-buffer)))
    (when (not (smerge-next-safe))
      (vc-find-conflicted-file)
      (if (eq buffer (current-buffer))
          (message "No conflicts found")
        (goto-char 0)
        (smerge-next-safe)))))

;; smerge-keep-current bound to smerge-command-prefix (RET) to keep the version the cursor is on.
;; smerge-keep-mine bound to smerge-command-prefix (m) to keep your changes.
;; smerge-keep-other bound to smerge-command-prefix (o) to keep other changes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no `smerge` does not provide that functionality.

Comment: Can it be done in combination with additional packages?

Comment: I don't know about such a package.